# How to switch to my default gpu?

Tags: windows-10

I have a msi low profile gtx 1050 and a g4560 but I can not run rocket league. I am think it is using my intel 610 but i do not know how to set my default gpu to my 1050. I also get this error on Nvidia control panel saying that i am not currently using a display attacthed to an Nvidia GPU. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

Desktop > Right Click > NVIDIA Control Panel > Manage 3D Settings > Global Settings > Set preferred graphcis processor to High-performance NVIDIA processor.

Note that it may be named differently due to my PC having the GeForce 820M not GTX 1050, but the default settings should all be in that control panel.

Comment: when i got to desktop and right click nvidia control panel doesnt come up

Comment: @AceTrix Mine is slow to load as well. Please try again and wait at least 30sec.

Comment: no i dont have an opinion to pick nvidia control panel when i right click in desktop

Comment: @AceTrix try  the following: Windows button + R > type control > look for NVIDIA Control Panel

Comment: it doesnt work still says i am not using nvidia gpu

Comment: do u think it is because my gpu is not plugged in?

Comment: i looked for the solution before and it said that i needed the plug my hdmi port into the gpu port

Comment: @AceTrix try looking for your NVIDIA GPU in device manager. I'm not sure plugging HDMI will work.

Comment: Let's cut to the chase... Do you *actually* have your monitor plugged into the NVidia or not? If the 2 GPUs have physically different outputs, then you're gonna actually have to plug something into it before you'll get anywhere at all.

Comment: in my device manager there is the gtx 1050 and it says it is working properly

Comment: @AceTrix Ok at least we've identified that you have a GTX (and you weren't ripped off, which is possible). Could you please describe your setup? E.g., how are your monitors connected to your computer?

Comment: my monitor is plugged into the normal port the one above and not the gpu port which it can not fit in

Comment: i dont know the name of my cable but it is blue and has 2 screws on the side

Comment: If you're not plugged into the NVidia, then the message you're getting is exactly right. btw, there is no such thing as a 'normal port' All these things have names, you need to Google what they are.

Comment: ok how do u exactly plug the port into nvidia?

Comment: the cable doesnt fit into the nvidia port

Comment: Take pictures of the back of the graphics card & the array of sockets on the back of the monitor. Take both pictures to your local computer shop & show them. Bring home the appropriate cable.

Comment: my back of the gpu is like this.https://linustechtips.com/main/uploads/monthly_2017_03/dvi.jpg.8bbe50e7481d0063066f5f79fd939643.jpg

Comment: That's a DVI-D connector

Comment: so i need that then plug my vga cable into it and thats how it will work?

Comment: DVI-D will not connect to VGA. You would need an active adaptor. Frankly, it would be more economical long-term to get a DVI/HDMI-capable monitor instead.